# log2vis.dll dependent dlls

Tags: dll

We are using log2vis.dll in one of our websites (it is a logical to visual fliper). Now we moved the website and the DLL to another server with the same configuration but we now get errors when the code tries to use the object in this DLL.
Does anyone know what dependencies this dll has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used a [decompiler](http://3d2f.com/tags/dll/decompiler/) to view the log2vis.dll dependencies. We saw that it needed msvbvm50.dll. We registered msvbvm50.dll and then log2vis.dll, and the peoblem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

For others who read this thread, [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is an excellent app for this.